# form validation error message doesn't show spring mvc thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I have add user form doesn't display the error message with thymeleaf. I try to read other solutions and apply other solutions in this forum but still doesn't work.

```
**userform.html** 

 <form  id="adduser" role="form"  th:action="@{/adduser}" method="post" th:object="${user}">


    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>First Name</label>
                                        <input class="form-control" th:field="*{first_name}"/>

                                          <p th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('first_name')}" th:errors="${user.first_name}">First name is mandatory</p>
                                    </div>
<button type="submit" name="action" value="adduser" class="btn btn-default" onclick="myFunction()">Submit</button>

  </form>
```

**My spring MVC controller**

**UserformController.java**

```
// Returns the view with model attached 
     @RequestMapping(value = "/userform", method = RequestMethod.GET) 
     public ModelAndView showuser(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) { 
        LOGGER.info("in get adduser"); 

        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView(); 

        mav.setViewName("userform"); 
        mav.addObject("user", new User()); 

        return mav; 

    } 

//Save 

    @RequestMapping(value = "/adduser", method = RequestMethod.POST) 
    public ModelAndView adduser(@Valid @ModelAttribute("userForm")  Userform user, BindingResult result, @RequestParam(value="action", required=true) String action) { 


        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView(); 

        if (result.hasErrors()) { 

            mav.setViewName("redirect:userform"); 
            mav.addObject("user", user); 
            return mav; 
        } 
else { 
            utilService.insert(user); 

            mav.setViewName("redirect:userlist"); 

            return mav; 
        } 

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you define any constraints in the User class? Please show the User class.

The errors would be based on the constraints in the properties of the User class, so there should be something like this

```
public class User {

    @NotNull
    private String first_name;

}
```

Comment: yeah i have this even checking size

Comment: Not sure if it affects anything but why th:errors="${user.first_name}"? why not th:errors="*{first_name}"?

Comment: @Link is right. the correct way is `th:errors="*{first_name}"`

Comment: do you think redirect refreshing everything

Comment: How about not using a redirect? That's the only other difference (aside from the th:errors) I can see from what I normally do.